# Reputation gained for question/answer edits are reversed

Tags: support, status-bydesign

This morning I have realized that reputation earned for suggested edits of questions/answers is reversed while everything was correct in peer review.

Under what conditions will my earned reputation for suggested edits be reversed?

Comment: Hopefully your motivation to suggest edits is driven more by making the site better than a couple of Internet points here and there. The extra reputation is nice, but it's impossible to control what happens after your edit has been accepted. As Jon pointed out below, if the post is deleted, you lose any rep gained from it - same is true for the owner of the post. The rep from that is reversed, and it also trickles down to anyone who down-voted the post, too (in the case of an answer); they get their -1 back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation earned on suggested edits is lost when a post is deleted. For instance, [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81565/ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended-where-function) was deleted, so all reputation gained from it was reversed.